# Pandas NaT's to -1?

Tags: python, timestamp, pandas

```
In [22]: ts
Out[22]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[NaT, ..., 2012-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 11, Freq: None, Timezone: None

In [23]: ts.year
Out[23]: array([  -1, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012])
```

This happens when using apply as well

```
ts.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).year)

0       -1
1     2012
2     2012
3     2012
4     2012
5     2012
6     2012
7     2012
8     2012
9     2012
10    2012
Name: Dates
```

is it a bug that NaT.year == -1?

Comment: What is `ts`? This question is very incomplete.

Comment: What is Pandas? This question is very incomplete.

Comment: @rene: if you click on the tag "pandas" it'll take you to the tag description (or just hover over it.)

Comment: @DSM I missed that one...sorry

Comment: @Tinctorius: the very first few lines show what `ts` is, a `pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex` instance of length 11 whose first element is the `pandas` not-a-time marker.

Comment: I thought the code was self explanatory, but feel free to make suggestions on how to make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, so the implied question is: "is it a bug that NaT.year == -1 (when contained in a DatetimeIndex)?"

Comment: yes. I've updated my OP to make more clear.

Comment: What versions of `numpy` and `pandas` are you using? In particular, `numpy` 1.7+ (with native `datetime64('nat')`), or 1.6- (where `pandas` has to fake it)?

Comment: Also, what did you _expect_ here? `float('nan')`? `None`? `0`? An exception?

Comment: I'd expect NaN, NaT, None. Anything other than -1 which can obviously cause problems down the road if gone unnoticed.

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: But integer arrays can't have `NaN`, `NaT`, or `None`. That's not a problem with `pandas`; it's true of every `numpy.array`, no matter where it comes from, if the `dtype` is integral. And you usually wouldn't want an `object` array. (OK, sometimes that would be acceptable, but if `numpy`/`pandas` did that in general, it would cause a lot more problems than it would solve.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you think this is a bug, rather than defined behavior?

First:

```
In [16]: pandas.NaT.year
Out[16]: -1
```

So, there's nothing odd about it being in a `DatetimeIndex`; that's how `NaT` always works.

And it's entirely internally consistent, as well as consistent with lots of other stuff in `numpy` and elsewhere that uses -1 as a special value for (hopefully unsigned) integral types.

Yes, -1 doesn't really work as a NaN, since you can do arithmetic with it and get non-NaN (and incorrect) results, and it does odd things in some other cases (try `pandas.NaT.isoformat()`), but what other option is there? As long as `year` is defined to be some kind of `numpy` integral type, it has to return an integral value. So, what are the options?

- Return either an `int` or `None`. Then calling `year` returns an `array(dtype=object)`.
- Return a float, so `NaT.year` can be `NaN`.
- Raise an exception for `NaT.year` itself, or when trying to do it within an `array`.
- Return some special integer value. If not -1, what value would you use?

They all suck in different ways, but the last seems to suck least, and be the most consistent with everything else in the universe. The ideal solution might be to have integer-with-NaN types in `numpy`, but that's a much larger issue that designing a wrapper around `numpy` `datetime`s…

By the way, it's worth noting that `numpy` 1.6 doesn't have a NaT value for `datetime64`, so a `pandas.NaT` actually maps to `datetime64(-1)`, for exactly the same reasons. Now that `numpy` 1.7 has `np.datetime64('NaT')`, that could change. But that still doesn't change the fact that integers don't have a NaN.

Comment: Hey, if that's how it works and it's the best available solution--then so be it. But as somebody whose just trying to get from point A to point B, the -1 can cause problems like you said.

Comment: @ChrisArmstrong: Yes, it can—as I said, "They all suck in different ways". Even with the "ideal solution" of integer NaN values, that would _still_ cause problems for many use cases (not to mention confusing people with `int16` ranges being smaller than they expect, etc., and being much harder to optimize). Dealing with the oddities of non-values is something that always comes up in numeric programming, and nobody's yet found a way to sweep them all under the rug.

Comment: The -1 is really just a placeholder until proper NA-in-integer-arrays is available.

Comment: @WesMcKinney: Is `numpy` seriously considering adding such a thing this time? Last time this came up (that I noticed), the conclusion seemed to be that reserving a special invalid value was not acceptable unless that value were user-specifiable, in which case it's just a less-powerful version of `MaskedArray`.

Comment: @WesMcKinney: By the way, my favorite suggestion was the one that added "affinely-extended integer" types like `aint16` or `auint64` that took away the bottom two and top one value (for signed) or top three values (for unsigned). It seems simple and obvious to me…